# Primeng data table change expander icon to button and pass data on expand event

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-turbotable, rowexpansion

Hi I am using row expansion feature of primeng Datatable as in
[image]

I want to achieve two things,

1. Change the expander icon to a button.
2. register row data in the controller on click of expander icon.

Please help in achieving this.

Comment: Hi. Could you maybe provide some more information, some code you already have and be more specific of your question, like, not demanding "how to"?

Comment: Hi I want to change the expander icon to a button and register the particular row in my component..